# Credit Cards and Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

A credit    card    company mails   out advertisements to   prospective customers,  and $0.4$% of  these   advertisements are  returned to the company due to  an  incorrect   or  invalid address. If the company sends   $250$  advertisements, find the    probability that    three   will    be  returned.

I claim that this is a Poisson Process. Letting our mean be $(250)(0.004) = 1$, then plugging into the pmf formula gives $\frac {1}{6e}$. However, this was marked incorrect. I am not sure why this is the case but any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a binomial distribution?

Comment: Even if it were, the probability would be almost identical to 1/6e. I'm not sure why a Binomial Process would fit this better than a Poisson one though?

Comment: It's not an unreasonable answer.  I'd have said that each ad had an independent probability of $.004$  but that comes to a very similar answer.

Comment: Note that $1/6e$ should formally be read as $\frac 16e$ rather than $\frac 1{6e}$, which I suspect is what you mean.  Parentheses, please if you are going to use the slash.

Comment: Of course, you are assuming that they meant "exactly $3$".  Perhaps they meant "at least $3$"?

Comment: There is no theoretical reason to prefer one model over the other...all of the data is, clearly, fuzzy anyway.  For that matter you could use the normal approximation between $2.5$ and $3.5$.  That gives $0.060296$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are expected to model it as a binomial distribution, so the probability would be ${250 \choose 3}0.004^3\cdot 0.996^{247}\approx 0.0611894$, while $\frac 1{6e} \approx 0.061313$.  I don't think your data is good enough to tell the difference between these.

Binomial is correct if you have a specific number of events with a given probability. Poisson is the limit of the binomial as the number of events goes to infinity, the probability of each event goes to zero, and the product is constant.

Comment: The question did imply exactly 3 although I'm still not sure why a Binomial Process is assumed over a Poisson one?

Comment: Binomial is correct if you have a specific number of events with a given probability.  Poisson is the limit of the binomial as the number of events goes to infinity, the probability of each event goes to zero, and the product is constant.

Comment: I see, so Binomial would be more appropriate then.